# Check if EKEvent already exists iPhone

Tags: ios, ekevent

I am trying to add an event to the calendar from my app, but it seems that I can add it as many times as I want. I only want to add it once, so how can I check if the event already exists? I have tried to set the eventIdentifier property, but it seems that it is readOnly.

Comment: Your application should keep track of eventIdentifiers of the events you added from within your app. Then you can simply check if the event with certain eventIdentifier exists already or not.

Comment: how do you keep track of eventIdentifiers, where do you store them?

Comment: you can store them in Core data or in your documents directory, depending on your app